# for loop not looping actual number in python

Tags: python

MY program is outputting score for competitor is 7 each time instead of the number of the competitor
Can someone help me fix this(The program is not entirely done yet and I know there are other wrong issues in the program, can you please address only the "j not looping issue" and not the other ones)

```
numJudges = 7
numCompetitors = int(input("Enter number of competitors(between 3 and 16 inc)" ))


for comp in range(0,numCompetitors):
    totalC = 0

    print("input scores between 0 and 10 for each Judge")

    for j in range(0, numJudges):
        j = j+1
        scoreJ = int(input("Score for judge"))

        totalC = totalC + scoreJ

    scoreC = totalC / numJudges 
    print("Score for competitor ", j ," is", scoreC)
```

Comment: You're outputting `j` outside of the inner loop. That loop will stop as soon as `j` becomes equal to `numJudges`.

Comment: Also, you are incrementing `j` inside of a loop which increments j automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` isn't the number of your competitor - it's the ID of the last judge.

You need to be outputting `comp` in the last line instead.

```py
print("Score for competitor ", comp ," is", scoreC)
```

Answer (score 0):

your last line should be:
`print("Score for competitor ", comp+1 ," is", scoreC)`